# Friction on a rod resting against a rough horizontal rail?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, rigid-body-dynamics, statics

In which direction does friction act on a rod leaning on a rough horizontal rail, where the normal force is perpendicular to the rod and the rod has its bottom end on a smooth horizontal floor with which it makes angle theta?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the free body diagram of the rod is

[image: fbd]

In red is the weight going through the center of the rod. In pink are the normal forces where the rod rests on the ground and rail. And in orange are the friction forces associated with the normal forces. I assumed the rod is trying to slide downwards in the absence of friction.

If in the course of calculating these forces, they end up with a negative sign, then you need to reverse the direction of the corresponding arrow.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Friction always acts in the reverse direction of a moving object. So if the end of the rod slides down, the frictional force would be applied in opposite direction or up in this case.

You should add a picture of your setup for problems like this.

Comment: Ah ok thank youIm not sure how to display a picture but I have added a link to an image which shows the set up. the roller is rough and the floor is smooth.